# Order of a group calculation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Order of groups/permutations question, its very simple, but i'm having trouble understanding it.

Why is the order of $(1372)(46)(5) : 4?$ 
By my understanding the LCM means its $4 \times 2 \times 1 = 8!$

I'm confused because the order of $(14367)(25)(8)$ is $10$, by LCM $5 \times 2 \times 1 = 10.$

Am I missing something very simple here, would really appreciate any help regarding this

Comment: The Least Common Multiple of 4,2,1 is 4.

Answer (score 1):

As commented: The Least Common Multiple of $4,2,1$ is $4$.